# Delete point after "author" that is not a person

Tags: biblatex, punctuation, apa-style

I want to cite a corporation as an "author" in my references. However, there is always a point between the "author" and the "year" in the references. Normally this makes sense, as the typical author has a given name and the point serves to abbreviate the name. E.g., "Miller, T." for Tom Miller.

For a corporation, that does not make sense. How can I delete the point? It looks like this: "Corporation. (2019)." I want to have it like this: "Corporation (2019)." I am using biblatex (with biber) and my style is APA.

```
\documentclass[12pt, titlepage, openright]{report}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber,natbib=true,uniquename=false]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
```

`.bib` entry

```
@Book{BMW_2012,
  title  = {{BMW i Ventures investiert in preisgekröntes Mobility-App Unternehmen Embark}},
  year   = {2012},
  author = {BMW}},
  note   = {Retrieved from https://www.press.bmwgroup.com/deutschland/article/ \\ detail/T0134380DE/},
```

Comment: Welcome. You will need to provide information about what system (bibtex, biblatex) and style you use. But TBH this is probably rather tricky, and will I think require biblatex and possibly some rather ad hoc adjustments. Why do you want this? If the Corporation is the author, isn't it *right* to punctuate it thus?

Comment: Could you post a minimal code illustrating the probelem. We do not even know which entry type is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2011/09/group-authors.html the period after a corporate author is actually correct behaviour

> > American Psychological Association. (n.d.). About APA. Retrieved from
> >         http://www.apa.org/about/
>
> Notice that the author portion still ends with a period.

There are also a few examples that show this behaviour in the [`biblatex-apa` example document](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-apa/biblatex-apa-test.pdf), in particular `7.03:31`, `7.10:72`, `7.02:28`, `7.08:54`, `7.03:35`, `7.03:32` (if I'm not mistaken at least some of those entries are real example from the respective sections of the APA manual, in case you want to double-check).

---

If you still want to go against APA style and want to suppress the period (I strongly advise against that), then I can offer the following solution where you have to manually set an `option` in the `.bib` entry.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\newtoggle{bbxapa@suppressauthoryearperiod}
\DeclareEntryOption[boolean]{suppressauthoryearperiod}[true]{%
  \settoggle{bbxapa@suppressauthoryearperiod}{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifnameundef{author}
    {\usebibmacro{labeltitle}}
    {\printnames[apaauthor][-\value{listtotal}]{author}%
     \setunit*{\addspace}%
     \printfield{nameaddon}%
     \ifnameundef{with}
       {}
       {\setunit{}\addspace\mkbibparens{\printtext{\bibstring{with}\addspace}%
        \printnames[apaauthor][-\value{listtotal}]{with}}
        \setunit*{\addspace}}}%
  \iftoggle{bbxapa@suppressauthoryearperiod}
    {\setunit{\addspace}}
    {\newunit}%
  \newblock%
  \usebibmacro{labelyear+extradate}}

\renewbibmacro*{editorinauthpos}{%
    \global\booltrue{bbx:editorinauthpos}%
    \printnames[apaauthor][-\value{listtotal}]{editor}%
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    \ifnameundef{editor}
      {}
      {\printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{apaeditorstrg}{editor}}%
       % need to clear editor so we don't get an "In" clause later
       % But we also need to set a flag to say we did this so we
       % don't lose sight of the fact we once had an editor for
       % various year placement tests
       \clearname{editor}%
       \iftoggle{bbxapa@suppressauthoryearperiod}
         {\setunit{\addspace}}
         {\setunit{\adddot\addspace}}%
       \usebibmacro{labelyear+extradate}%
       \setunit{\adddot\addspace}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{BMW_2012,
  title  = {BMW i Ventures investiert in preisgekröntes Mobility-App Unternehmen Embark},
  year   = {2012},
  author = {{BMW}},
  url    = {https://www.press.bmwgroup.com/deutschland/article/detail/T0134380DE/},
  langid = {ngerman},
  options = {suppressauthoryearperiod},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{BMW_2012}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: BMW (2012). BMW i Ventures investiert in preisgekröntes Mobility-App Unternehmen Embark. Retrieved from https://www.press.bmwgroup.com/deutschland/article/detail/T0134380DE/]

I did not want to add an 'automatic' solution because there is no way to tell a corporate author like "BMW" from a person with only a single name like "Plato" or "Madonna".

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying the author inside a `\bibcorporate{}`?

From [apacite manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/apacite/apacite.pdf):

> author
>
> The author(s) of the work. This may also be a corporate author when applicable, but some specific measures must then be taken to prevent the corporate name from being interpreted as a first name and last name (such as “Association, A. P.”):
>
> `author = {{\bibcorporate{American Psychological Association}}},`
>
> It is important to surround the `\bibcorporate{Author}` by an additional pair of braces.

Comment: Thanks but that seems to be not working with biblatex...